# remove lines where a field's value is less than or equal to 3 - sed or awk?

Tags: shell, shell-script, sed, awk, grep

I need to remove every line that has a value of 2 or less in the 8th field (column).

My data looks like this:

```
12-31   Airport 189 379 41  49.70946503 -124.91377258   2   2880    30.8
01-01   AlberniElementary   165 331 16  49.26100922 -124.80662537   4   5760    26.1
01-09   BamfieldMarine  161 323 23  48.83490372 -125.13572693   2   2875    27.4
01-10   BamfieldMarine  161 323 23  48.83490372 -125.13572693   3   3068    38.6
```

I understand that using awk I can strip off the values desired and print them to another file, and I understand that sed would edit the current file. In either case, I need to retain the original file.

**Note**:
Please provide thorough explanations with your solutions. It is not suffice to just write the command, please annotate suggestions.

**Further note**: The data has a header line, so most likely solution will need to

> awk 'FNR >1'

I suppose?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You almost got it.

```
 awk '(NR>1) && ($8 > 2 ) ' foo > bar
```

where

- `NR` is number of record (that is number of line)
- `$8` is eight field
- `&&` is logical and
- `foo` is the original file, unchanged
- `bar` resulting file
- implicit default action is to print the current input line

Note that header is striped from foo to bar, to keep it

```
 awk '(NR==1) || ($8 > 2 ) ' foo > bar
```

where

- `||` is logical or
- input line is printed if NR==1 or if $8 > 2

#### Update #1

To specify a range

- `( ($8 >= -4) && ( $8 <= 4 ) )` 8th field from -4 to 4
- `(NR == 1 ) || ( ($8 >= -4) && ( $8 <= 4 ) )` same, including header

Comment: Great answer: simple yet thorough, thanks. Just so i'm clear, the difference between FNR and NR in this case is nothing, correct? I have read the _man_ page where it explains: NR ordinal number of the current record & FNR ordinal number of the current record in the current file. So I understand these being equal in this case, I think :)

Comment: If you have one file, FNR is always NR, if file1 has 10 lines, first line of file2 would have NR=11 and FNR=1

Comment: Hi I want to do something similar but accept everything in a range of -4 to 4. how would I go about doing this, as this is the only way I can think of doing it currently awk '(NR==1) || ($8 = [-4-4] ) ' foo > bar

Comment: awk doesn't know about math style range, see my edit.